# Parse csv data with PHP to display rows with unique columns

Tags: php, csv

The goal is to process a list of rows with unique data in a specific column from a csv file. It should only list the top 5 reasons for calls in order and how many total instances for each.

Data Example:

### userid | reason_for_call

abc1   | Issues with printing

abc2   | Issues with internet

abc3   | Issues with email

abc8   | Issues with email

abc1   | Issues with printing

abc4   | Issues with printing

abc7   | Issues with email

abc4   | Issues with email

abc6   | Issues with scanning

abc1   | Issues with scanning

abc6   | Issues with faxing

When parsed, it should display something like:

Top 5 reasons: 
Issues with email (4 calls) 
Issues with printing (3 calls) 
Issues with scanning (2 calls) 
Issues with faxing (1 calls) 
Issues with internet (1 calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should collect all of the `reasons_for_call` into an array and use `array_count_values()` and go from there.

```
<?php

$reasons = [];

//Collect all of the call reasons.
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ","); //Skip first row.
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $reasons[] = $data[1];
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

//Count each of the values and sort the array by the value.
$values = array_count_values($reasons);
arsort($values);

//Get the first 5 elements in the array, and output as desired.
foreach(array_slice($values, 0, 5) as $reason => $count){
    echo $reason . " (" . $count . " calls)\n";
}
```

Input:

```
userid,reason_for_call
abc1,Issues with printing
abc2,Issues with internet
abc3,Issues with email
abc8,Issues with email
abc1,Issues with printing
abc4,Issues with printing
abc7,Issues with email
abc4,Issues with email
abc6,Issues with scanning
abc1,Issues with scanning
abc6,Issues with faxing
```

Output:

```
Issues with email (4 calls)
Issues with printing (3 calls)
Issues with scanning (2 calls)
Issues with internet (1 calls)
Issues with faxing (1 calls)
```